# Rancid scripts for Brocade Fiber Channel Switches?

Tags: networking, storage-area-network, backup, brocade

I am looking for [Rancid](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) scripts for my [Brocade 5100](http://www.brocade.com/products/all/switches/product-details/5100-switch/index.page)s. Does anyone have a secret stash they would be willing to share?

Comment: woohoo! Tumbleweed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the scripts from here, with a little change for getting the whole config
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rancid/users/5454

In brocaderancid

```
@commandtable = (
    {'chassisShow'  => 'ChassisShow'},
    {'firmwareShow' => 'FirmwareShow'},
  {'version'            => 'FirmwareShow'},
    #{'fosConfig --show'        => 'Fosconfig'},
    {'ipAddrShow'       => 'IpAddrShow'},
  {'licenseShow'    => 'LicenseShow'},
    {'domainsShow'  => 'DomainsShow'},
    {'configupload -force -l config.txt'    => 'ConfigUploadlocal'},
    {'configshow -l config.txt'     => 'ConfigShow'}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a couple of additional modifications to get this to work for me on my SLKWRM0000200 running Fabric OS v6.2.2b.

I had to add the following to the %vendortable array in rancid-fe:
    'brocade'           => 'brocaderancid',

Then I used "brocade" as the system type in router.db like so:
fc-sw03:brocade:up

I also had to change "set avautoenable 1" in brocadelogin since the username that rancid uses has an admin role.  If i could figure out how to create a read-only user that would have access to enough info, I'd use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The:

```
{'configupload -force -l config.txt'    => 'ConfigUploadlocal'},
{'configshow -l config.txt'     => 'ConfigShow'}
```

approach did not work for me, so I went with:

```
{'configShow -a'    => 'ConfigShow'}
```

in order to get the complete configuration